# React this.setState not rerendering

Tags: reactjs

So I have this class:

```
class TaskList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tasks: []
    };

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get("/api/all").then(result => {
      this.setState({
        tasks: result.data
      });
    });
  }

  handleDelete(id) {
    axios.delete(`/api/${id}`).then(res => {
      axios.get("/api/all").then(tasks => {
        this.setState({
          tasks: tasks.data
        });
      });
    });
  }

  handleEdit(id, updatedTask) {
    axios.put(`/api/${id}`, updatedTask).then(res => {
      axios.get("/api/all").then(tasks => {
        console.log(tasks);
        this.setState({
          tasks: tasks.data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { tasks } = this.state;
    console.log('list render');
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="title row col-lg-6 mx-auto">
          <div className="col-sm-4">{"Date"}</div>
          <div className="col-sm-4">{"Task"}</div>
          <div className="col-sm-4">{"Status"}</div>
        </div>
        {tasks.map(i => (
          <div className={`${i._id} task mx-auto col-lg-6`}>
            <div className={`${i._id} row`}>
              <Task
                key={i._id}
                id={i._id}
                title={i.title}
                date={i.date}
                complete={i.complete}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Task component

```
class Task extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(props.date),
      complete: props.complete
    };

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleDelete() {
    this.props.handleDelete(this.props.id);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const updatedTask = {
      title: this.props.title,
      complete: !this.state.complete
    };
    this.setState({ complete: !this.state.complete });
    this.props.handleEdit(this.props.id, updatedTask);
  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    const { date, complete} = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className='col-sm-4'>
          {date.getFullYear() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getDate()}
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4">{title}</div>
        <div className="col-sm-3" onClick={this.handleClick}><Status complete={complete}/></div>
        <div className="col-sm-1" onClick={this.handleDelete}><IconClose /></div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Status component

```
const Status = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <>
      {props.complete ? (
        <i className="far fa-check-square" />
      ) : (
        <i className="far fa-square" />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

My problem that I am having is on my handleEdit I am not getting the component to re render with the updated task list. The handleDelete function works and updates the screen fine but not the edit.

I always thought setState would cause a re render and then I also tried forceUpdate but it didn't work either.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Have you done any lifecycle debugging to make sure the data is being updated by your XHR methods?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I have, in Task there is a line console.log(`${this.props.title} and ${this.props.complete}`); in the render function that is showing the axios calls are working

Comment: Can you put error callback for your edit to see if the call is failing and thus unable to re-render and if Task component has latest data then the component is re-rendering. Also, put axios.get into a separate function call(DRY) and easier to debug. Use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount lifecycle method for api calls.

Comment: Can you please add catch block in edit function API calls , then post the error if any.

Comment: Added the catches that were asked for, no errors were thrown. I also included the other components that are being used in this code.

Comment: Which state is not being updated? The Task state or the TaskList state?

Comment: It is not rerendering the status component again. So it should show a checked box when true and an empty box when false. It will show properly if I reload the page, but not when just clicking the component

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is a forking of props into state.

Inside `Task`, the code calls `this.props.handleEdit(this.props.id, updatedTask)`, which sends the data to the parent component `TaskList`. That `handleEdit` function updates the state key `tasks` of `TaskList`.

However, when the completeness state of each task is passed to `Task`, its forked from `props` into its own component state:

```
this.state = {
  ...
  complete: props.complete
};
```

The `constructor` function is only called once; `props.complete` can never update state again. My suggestion is to use props as they are passed from `TaskList`, unless you must store their completeness value inside of `Task` for a specific reason.

The React docs explain this common anti-pattern:

> The problem is that it’s both unnecessary (you can use `this.props.color` directly instead), and creates bugs (updates to the color prop won’t be reflected in the state).
>
> Only use this pattern if you intentionally want to ignore prop updates.

[React constructor docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)